# Ionic stop working after inserting jQuery script

Tags: jquery, ios, ionic-framework

In a Ionic view, if I insert this script:

```
<script>
    jQuery(function(){
        jQuery('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
            loop:true,
            center: true,
            responsive:{
                0:{
                    items:3
                },
                600:{
                    items:3
                }
            }
        })
    });
</script>
```

My app start returning errors like this:

- Error: element[0] is undefined htmlAnchorDirective<.compile/
- Error: node is undefined compositeLinkFn

And things like "hide-nav-bar="true"" stopped working.

Any idea on what may be happening?

Comment: you shouldn't be mixing jQuery with Angular, that is what angular is for.